# Does Pidgin have input history?

Tags: pidgin

Most chat clients allow the user to scroll though the input history with the up and down arrow keys.  Pidgin does not seem to support this.  Is there some other way to retrieve past input without copying and pasting?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  As mentioned in this [feature request](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/17504/) you can scroll through your input history with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>.